# Why isn’t ReadOnlyDictionary thread-safe?

Tags: concurrency, dictionary, thread-safety, immutability, .net-4.5

I’m looking for a readonly-dictionary to be accessed from multiple threads.  While ConcurrentDictionary exposes such capabilities, I don’t want to have the overhead and the strange API.

.Net 4.5 while providing such a class, the documentation states that only static calls are safe.

I wonder why?

Comment: Copy from Microsoft document:

Thread Safety
All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: @KenCheung: It's not clear why your comment is relevant. The question indicates that the OP is already aware of `ConcurrentDictionary<,>`, but is asking about the safety of `ReadOnlyDictionary<,>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`ReadOnlyDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875.aspx) is just a wrapper around any other dictionary. As such, it's only as thread-safe as the underlying dictionary.

In particular, if there's a thread modifying the underlying dictionary while another thread reads from the wrapper, there's no guarantee of safety.

If you want a `ReadOnlyDictionary` which is effectively immutable from *all* angles, you can create a clone of the original dictionary, create a `ReadOnlyDictionary` wrapper around that, and then not keep a reference to the clone anywhere. With *only* read operations going on, it should then be thread-safe. Of course, if the key or value types are mutable, that opens up a second degree of "thread-unsafety" to worry about.

Comment: Just a clarification. Read-only does not imply thread-safe. What if the dictionary rearranges the items based on read usage? The BCL dictionaries does not do it (AFAIK) but I read somewhere that Scripting.Dictionary moves the last read item to the first position in the bucket.

Comment: @adrianm: Yes, that's true. But you could wrap a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` which was never modified, and *that* would be okay.

Comment: Regarding 'should' - it isn't strictly guaranteed to be as thread-safe as we'd expect, right? If this answer is accurate, we're into 'unofficially thread-safe' behavior here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28960891/

Comment: @MaxBarraclough: The `Dictionary` documentation explicitly says "A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified." So if the `ReadOnlyDictionary` wraps a `Dictionary`, and that's never modified after initialization, I think it's fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Perfect. I'd missed that.

Comment: @JonSkeet So let's say I have to add & delete objects from the underlying dictionary as the life of my application proceeds. I've wrapped all adds & deletes, loops, and gets against that underlying dictionary with lock statements, so my access to that dictionary is thread-safe everywhere. I'm guessing that the ReadOnlyDictionary's access to my dictionary isn't protected since it can't know about my lock object. How do I make that thread-safe?

Comment: @TonyVitabile: I suspect you might need to write your own implementation of IReadOnlyDictionary to do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I had a feeling that was going to be the answer. But I figured it couldn't hurt to ask!

Comment: @TonyVitabile but it hurt, didn't it?  You would have to protect the read methods with the same lock, I suspect? You just want to make sure, an add or remove operation is finished when you are trying to read something.

Comment: @ElMac Well, no, it didn't hurt, because I was asking a hypothetical question. I don't currently have a need for such a construct; I was just asking because the question came to mind while reading the other comments. And now that I know the answer, if I do need one in the future, I can write it correctly.