# Return read only version of a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have a class which contains a private ConcurrentDictionary to store some stuff. Now I want to allow consumers of this class the query the contents of it using LINQ extensions methods. The question is how can I return a read only version of the contents of the dictionary that is read only.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want it to reflect changes?

Comment: @SLaks Yes I basically want it to be a ConcurrentDictionary just with no modification methods

Comment: Why not just expose the read methods in your class, accessing the underlying private field?

Comment: You can use a `ReadOnlyDictionary` for that. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13684219/2846483).

Comment: The odds of this being an appropriate usage of the dictionary are extremely low.  You'd be accessing stale data of the dictionary, so there are few safe ways to actually act on whatever data you get out.

Comment: @Servy That's not the case. ConcurrentDictionary can be updated while iterating through it and the new keys will be visibile. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: As Servy said, this is quite rare that you need to expose a whole `Dictionnary`. Which actions (or LINQ queries as you named it) your consumers must be able to do on the data contained in this dictionnary ?

Comment: @Spotted How can this be rare. I just want users to be able to query data which is updated using logic in the actual class. I'm imagining users using Where, Aggregate, Any, Select, All, First, FirstOrDefault, GroupBy... I can go on and on. It's just the same as someone being able to query a list of data but not modify it. The entire reason getters and setters exists.

Comment: @JohnSmith The dictionary won't crash when you query it while updating it, you'll just have stale data, so you can't reliably *act* on the information you get out, because the data is stale.  Instances in which it's appropriate to have said stale data are rather rare.

Comment: @Servy The data is not stale. See this note on the page I linked: "The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary, however it does not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary. The contents exposed through the enumerator may contain modifications made to the dictionary after GetEnumerator was called."

Comment: @JohnSmith The fact that you don't understand that that description is telling you that you're going to have stale data tells me that you are almost certainly not actually using this appropriately, and that your usage isn't appropriate.  The whole point of that description is that it's telling you that the results that you get very much can involve stale data.  Worse still, since it's not even just a snapshot, it's possible for some of it to be stale and some not, based on where in the iterator you were when changes happened.  That's much harder to use safely than even a snapshot.

Comment: @Servy No it's not stale it very clearly states modifications made the dictionary are visible to the while enumerating. Getting a snapshot means using stale data

Comment: @JohnSmith Both of them involve using stale data.  Getting a snapshot simply means all of the data is equally state.  Seeing changes while enumerating means that elements yielded earlier in the sequence are more stale than elements yielded later in the sequence.  They're all (potentially) stale, just not by the same amount, making reasoning about them that much harder.  But the data is stale before you even get access to it; that's the nature of accessing shared data between threads without blocking access to said data from those other threads.

Comment: @Servy Stale means old data. Enumerating over ConcurrentDictionary does not show old data. You simply have a race condition if you require changes to multiple keys to be atomic with respect to iterating over the dictionary. Which I don't have as a requirement and if you had that as a requirement ConcurrentDictionary is not the right choice and you have to use locks or some other synchronization primitive.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, and the data *is* old by the time you're able to act on it.  Every item that's yielded to you could have been removed from the dictionary by the time you do anything with the results that you get, or had its value changed, or have new values added that you aren't seeing, or any other possibilities.  You can make literally zero statements about what's in the dictionary after having iterated over it, only that at some point in the past each of those items yielded were in that dictionary (although not necessarily at the same time).  That makes it stale data.

Comment: @Servy Then any read of a ConcurrentDictionary is stale since literally once you read value it might have been removed a nanosecond afterwards before you use it. If you need this you have to use locks and lock the operation you want to do on the data as well as the read of the dictionary.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, that's correct, any read of a concurrent dictionary is necessarily stale, that's correct.  That's why just reading from it tends to be rather rare, particularly using an iterator, rather than querying a singular value.  That's why I said from the very start that the odds of this being an appropriate usage are low, because there just aren't many things that you can do with the result that are safe and meaningful.

Comment: @Servy This to me is just bonkers. A collection is a just collection of things. If you get something from it and someone else says this is no longer part of this collection doesn't mean you didn't get the thing from the collection. If you need this behaviour ConcurrentDictionary is an invalid choice and therefore I think your argument doesn't carry any weight.

Comment: So all you care about is getting a list of some of the things that have been in the collection, but no tall of them, and you don't care if they're in there any more?  What can you possibly do with that information?  Like I've said, there are things that you can theoretically do that are valid, but not many.  It's *quite* rare to be doing something like that.  You could have a good understanding of exactly what information you're getting back, how it can be safely used, and be sure that you're in such a situation, if so, that's fine, but if not, you need to reconsider what your'e doing.